# import rpy2 but can not import rpy2.robjects when changing start folders

Tags: python, import, anaconda, rpy2

The Current problem I am looking into is described below:
My computer is Win10, I installed only one anaconda 3.5.3 on it. Using `where python` there is only one python in my computer.
I downloaded a rpy2python wheel file from the uefi website, and install that using pip install.

When I import rpy2 in C disk, it is already fine, import rpy2,import rpy2.robjects are all OK.

But when I import rpy2 in my own project, I can only first import rpy2, when I import rpy2.robjects,the program says can not find rpy2 module.

Finally I found the problem is that in my project, I occasionaly established an rpy2.py file, when I first import rpy2, it where automatically create an rpy2.pycache folder, secondly when I import rpy2.robjects, Of Course the computer can not find an rpy2.robjects.

Just Keep a track of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check the Python documentation about import rules for modules. By default, having a file called `rpy2.py` in the working directory for your Python code will cause `import rpy2` to find this one rather that the rpy2 package.

The easiest fix is probably to rename your module `rpy2.py` into something else.